# How to show the excluded region in a scatter plot using margin or something else in mathamatica?

Tags: plotting

Here is my scatter plot[image]

I want show that the region lying in the range [Delta]=(0,40) and [Delta]=(140,190) is excluded. How do I show that? The code for my scatter plot is given below

```
Subscript[R, ν][δ_, θ12_, θ13_, ϵ_] := (2 \
ϵ)/(1/
     64 Sec[θ12 Degree]^4 Sec[
      2 θ12  Degree]^4 Sec[θ13  Degree]^10 (16 Cos[
         2 θ12  Degree]^4 Cos[θ13  Degree]^8 (1 + 
          Cos[2 θ12  Degree] Cos[θ13  Degree])^2 Sin[
         2 δ  Degree]^2 + (-4 Cos[
           2 θ12  Degree]^2 Cos[θ13  Degree]^3 (Cos[
              2 δ  Degree] Cos[θ13  Degree] (1 + 
               Cos[2 θ12  Degree] Cos[θ13  Degree]) + 
            Sin[θ13  Degree]^2) + 
         Sin[2 θ13  Degree]^2)^2));
Tab1 = Table[{δ, 
    Subscript[R, ν][δ, Random[Real, {30.002 , 36.6 }], 
     Random[Real, {7.816 , 9.021 }], 
     Random[Real, {.013, .017}]]}, {δ , 0 , 190 , 1 Degree}];
P1 = ListPlot[Abs[Tab1], Frame -> { True, True, True, True}, 
  PlotRange -> {0.02, 0.04}, 
  FrameLabel -> {δ, Subscript[R, ν] }, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}]
```

Comment: Doesn't the lack of points in those regions show that already? Or is that not what you mean? What visual cue are you trying to reproduce?

Comment: I just want to draw line or margin in the scatter plot at delta= 40 and delta=140. Can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add rectangles representing excluded regions. Modify `P1` as follows:

```
P1 = ListPlot[Abs[Tab1], Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
  PlotRange -> {0.02, 0.04}, 
  FrameLabel -> {\[Delta], Subscript[R, \[Nu]]}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14},
  Epilog -> {
    Lighter@Blend[{Blue, Cyan}, 0.4],
    Opacity[0.4],
    Rectangle[{-10, 0.020}, {40, 0.040}],
    Rectangle[{140, 0}, {200, 0.040}]
    }
  ]
```

[image]

You can adjust the `Opacity` and color or further modify `Ticks` if you want.

**EDIT**

If you want to draw delimiters only, modify `P1` as folows:

```
P1 = ListPlot[Abs[Tab1],
  Frame -> {True, True, True, True},
  PlotRange -> {0.02, 0.04},
  FrameLabel -> {\[Delta], Subscript[R, \[Nu]]}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14},
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Range[20, 180, 20], None}},
  GridLinesStyle -> {Dashed, Black},
  GridLines -> {{40, 140}, None},
  ImageSize -> Large
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Now if I need to add four margins vertically at  delta=45,50,140,150 and horizontally at Rnu=0.03,0.04, then how will I do it?

Comment: Mma calls them `GridLines`. Try: `GridLines -> {{45, 50, 140, 150}, {0.03, 0.04}}` but the line at 0.04 will not be visible (being at the edge of the frame itself). Also change: `GridLinesStyle -> {{Dashed, Black}, {Dashed, Black}}`

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

Subscript[
    R, ν][δ_, θ12_, θ13_, ϵ_] := (2 \
ϵ)/(1/
      64 Sec[θ12 Degree]^4 Sec[
       2 θ12 Degree]^4 Sec[θ13 Degree]^10 (16 Cos[
          2 θ12 Degree]^4 Cos[θ13 Degree]^8 (1 + 
           Cos[2 θ12 Degree] Cos[θ13 Degree])^2 Sin[
          2 δ Degree]^2 + (-4 Cos[
             2 θ12 Degree]^2 Cos[θ13 Degree]^3 (Cos[
               2 δ Degree] Cos[θ13 Degree] (1 + 
                Cos[2 θ12 Degree] Cos[θ13 Degree]) + 
             Sin[θ13 Degree]^2) + 
          Sin[2 θ13 Degree]^2)^2));

SeedRandom[1234];

Tab1 = Table[{δ,
    Subscript[R, ν][δ, Random[Real, {30.002, 36.6}],
     Random[Real, {7.816, 9.021}], Random[Real, {.013, .017}]]},
   {δ, 0, 190, 1 Degree}];

P1 = ListPlot[Abs[Tab1],
  Frame -> True,
  PlotRange -> {0.02, 0.04},
  FrameLabel -> {δ, Subscript[R, ν]},
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14},
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  ColorFunction ->
   Function[{d, r}, If[40 < d < 140, Blue, Red]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  GridLines -> {{40, 140}, None},
  GridLinesStyle ->
   Directive[Gray, AbsoluteThickness[1], Dashed]]
```

[image]

Comment: How do I edit the code if I want to get lines at delta=45,50,140,150?

Comment: See the docs for `GridLines`